# What's the trick for fixed positioned elements inside a liquid layout?

Tags: css, css-position

So I have a fixed positioned element that resides in an expanding element.

What's the trick to keep it in the same place whether the browser is at 1024px wide or 2000px ?

Answer (score 0):

The fixed-size element must be `display:block`, and have a `margin:0 auto`. To have fixed position, position has to be set via javascript, and updated when the window is resized.

Comment: I set both the fixed positioned element to display:block and the element it is inside. gave the outer margin: 0 auto. Still when the browser is resized the fixed postioned inside moves to the left. How should I set the margins form the fixed element? If I could use a negative right margin rather than a large left margin that would seem ideal

Comment: @winchendonsprings The fixed-width div should have `margin:0 auto`, not the expanding one.

Comment: ohh and then use padding from the outside element to position it?

Comment: w4mail There's no full css way that you can think of?